# Multipart request with Android SDK25

Tags: android, multipartform-data

All my search results for sending multipart requests require `HttpClient`, which was apparently removed in SDK23. Fix for this is to import legacy libraries.

As of SDK25, Whats the "proper" way to do this without importing such legacy libraries?

If it makes a difference, I'm sending files and JSON in my request.

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request

Answer (score 0):

Using refrofit2 to make such request.https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-upload-files. Or use the okHTTP3 client.http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: those libraries are fantastic type annotations are lovely.